# VBA Slicer Copy Method

Tags: vba, excel, copy, slicers

I'm completely new with VBA and Excel Macro and what I want to do is simply this:

I want that as soon as I click a data in a slicer, it will automatically be copied in the clipboard.

My Slicer Name is: Slicer_Internal_Punter_ID

Please let me know, if you still need additional info. I thought it would be easy but I'm now going crazy.

Thanks. I would gladly appreciate it.

[image: This is the slicer]

and here is the slicer details

[image].

Comment: This site is not a free coding service. If you are new to VBA you may want to start with something less complex.

Comment: alright still thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following procedure and event to get the name of the selected items.

Add this procedure to any module and use the immediate window (View/Immediate window) to read and copy the correct name of the SliceCache. It need to be used in the other snippet.

```
Sub GetSlicerData()

    '## Variables ##

    Dim iSlicerCache            As SlicerCache      'Slicer Cache Object
    Dim iSlicerItem             As SlicerItem       'Slicer Item
    Dim iSlicer                 As Slicer           'Slicer Object

    '## Looping through Slicer Caches in 'ThisWorkbook' ##

    For Each slSlicerCache In ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches

        Debug.Print ("Slicer Cache Namee: " & slSlicerCache.Name)   'Printing the name property of the SlicerCaches

        '## Looping through Slicers contained in the SlicerCaches ##

        For Each iSlicer In slSlicerCache.Slicers
                Debug.Print ("Slicer Name: " & iSlicer.Name)    'Printing the slicer names
                Next iSlicer

        '## Looping through Items contained in the SlicerCaches ##
                    'and testing selection status

        For Each iSlicerItem In slSlicerCache.SlicerItems
                If iSlicerItem.Selected = True Then Debug.Print ("Selected Item: " & iSlicerItem.Name)                            'Printing the slicer items
                Next iSlicerItem

        Next slSlicerCache

        End Sub
```

The second snippet is a worksheet event that has to be added to the sheet which is impacted by the slicer.

Double click on the sheet in the macro editor (project explorer windows) to add the code:
[Adding the Event to the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv53T.jpg)

The second snippet will print the selected items to the immediate windows.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        'Debug.Print ("Sheet name: " & Me.Name)  'Sheet name

    '## Looping through Slicer Caches in 'ThisWorkbook' ##

    Dim slcSlicerCache          As SlicerCache      'Slicer Cache Object
    Dim iSlicerItem             As SlicerItem       'Slicer Item

    Dim stItems                 As String

    '## Setting slicer cache ##

    'Replace with the correct name: "Slicer_Internal_Punter_ID"

    Set slcSlicerCache = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Internal_Punter_ID")

    For Each iSlicerItem In slcSlicerCache.SlicerItems
                If iSlicerItem.Selected = True Then

                Debug.Print ("Selected Item: " & iSlicerItem.Name)  'Printing selected

                    If Len(stItems) = 0 Then stItems = iSlicerItem.Name Else stItems = stItems & vbNewLine & iSlicerItem.Name

                End If
                Next iSlicerItem

                Debug.Print ("Selected Items: " & vbNewLine & stItems)  'Printing selected

                    'ADD CODE HERE: moving content to clipboard

    End Sub
```

Please be care to using the correct name of the slicer in this line:

```
Set slcSlicerCache = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Internal_Punter_ID")
```

Additionally to post the item names to clipboard you can check the following link: [How to copy text to clipboard](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/1/13/how-to-use-vba-code-to-copy-text-to-the-clipboard)